# How can I extract user data from a file with awk and create a new user based on it?

Tags: scripts, awk

I need somebody who could help an exercise. I can only **use shell scripting and `awk`** to do it:

You have a text file called users.txt with this info inside:

`users.txt`:

Peter:7777:/home/store ;

Quinn:7777:/home/accounts ;

David:7777:/home/secondstore ;

Daniel:7777:/home/address ;

The script should create an user using the first word of each line, the second word of each line will be used as password, and the third one as the home directory.

I would be very grateful If anybody can point me in the right direction

Comment: Google and do your homework. :)

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F: '{print $1}' users.txt` will give you access to the username field
`awk -F: '{print $2}' users.txt` --> password field
`awk -F: '{print $3}' users.txt` --> home directory field

you could do something like:

```
user=`awk -F: '{print $1}' users.txt`;
path=`awk -F: '{print $3}' users.txt`;
useradd -d $path -m $user;
```

Comment: The third awk is incorrect. It'll include the ` ;` from the end of the lines.

Comment: If I can use _sed_ I could do  **path=`awk -F: '{print $3}' users.txt` | sed 's/;$//';**

Comment: I can use sed, but the problem in this case is the ammount of data it saves... How can I put a vector inside an awk file?

Answer (score 2):

The both commands in the while loop need to be run as root, so either add `sudo`s or save this as a bash script and run that with `sudo` (probably preferable).

```
awk -F ':| ' '{print $1, $2, $3}' users.txt |
while read user password homedir; do
    adduser --home "$homedir" "$user"
    echo "$password" | passwd "$user" --stdin
done
```

---

Alternatively, as you've pointed out, you can do more inside `awk`. We can have it print the entire command:

```
$ awk -F ':| ' '{ print("adduser --home", $3, $1"; echo", $2 " | passwd", $1) }' users.txt
adduser --home /home/almacen1 Jperez; echo 1234 | passwd Jperez
adduser --home /home/contabilidad1 Lgomez; echo 1234 | passwd Lgomez
adduser --home /home/almacen2 Pfernandez; echo 1234 | passwd Pfernandez
adduser --home /home/direccion1 Mramos; echo 1234 | passwd Mramos
```

And then just have it pipe all that into a shell (while running):

```
$ awk -F ':| ' '{ print("adduser --home", $3, $1"; echo", $2 " | passwd", $1) | "/bin/bash" }' users.txt
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
passwd: user 'Jperez' does not exist
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
passwd: user 'Lgomez' does not exist
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
passwd: user 'Pfernandez' does not exist
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
passwd: user 'Mramos' does not exist
```

Obviously you would need to run the above with `sudo` (or as root) in order for it to run (that's why it's vomiting errors). You could use `awk`'s `system()` command but then you have to spend more time concatenating the strings. `print()` makes this really simple so I went with that.

Just for clarification, by that I mean to run `sudo awk -F ':| ' '{ print("adduser --home", $3, $1"; echo", $2 " | passwd", $1) | "/bin/bash" }' users.txt`

Comment: Don't need awk here: `while IFS=: read user password homedir; do ... done < users.txt` -- will have to trim trailing stuff from the line though.

Comment: @glennjackman sure, just the question asks for it explicitly.

Comment: the problem here is how the program knows that users are in the first field, the passwords are the second field of each line etc...?...thanks for your help

Comment: @marcosruiz I don't follow. awk processes the line logically And you've told us the order of the lines. That's how.

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty newbie at shellscripting...what do you mean by "logicaly"? one after anoter in a sequence?   ....   is there any way of doing this exercise with AWK and the SYSTEM command inside AWK? because that's the hint our teacher gave us(but he pointed there were other ways of doing the exercise without AWK)... thanks for your time and help

Comment: Left to right, yeah. Here I'm telling `awk` to split on spaces or colons and so it's splitting the line into 4 fields as it moves across. And huh, yeah, I never knew about `system()`. It might be GNU `awk` (`gawk`) specific though.

Comment: thanks again for your answer, Oli..so you mean that after executing in a shell: $ awk -F ':| ' '{ print("adduser --home", $3, $1"; echo", $2 " | passwd", $1) | "/bin/bash" }' users.txt as root (being "/bin/bash" the first script you told me: while read user password home....), this thing is done? because I don't know if I've done something wrong, but I don't see any new users(or am I understanding it wrong?)... I'm going to check it again

Comment: You should only need the last command. I've added a version that shows it with `sudo` just in case you're not following but yes, that should work.

Comment: That's what I first tried...but the error that appears is (running with sudo)    adduser: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
 via the NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.
passwd: user «Jperez» does not exist
 adduser: ....."

Answer (score 1):

Set the internal field separator to : and then simply ignore the last character of ; by any method... using substring or chomping it off.

This code should point you in the right direction.

**This is a random example of IFS var in use**

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$','
vals='/mnt,/var/lib/vmware/Virtual Machines,/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp,/usr/portage,/var/tmp'
for i in $vals; do echo $i; done
unset IFS
```

In your case you'd set IFS=: and run that type of code on every line.

For questions like these I recommend using a search engine or posting on a more programming friendly site.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean...do I only need to use IFS (by theway, we use "FS")?

Comment: could you please suggest me "a more programming friendly site"? thanks for your help